# in unix, read the file name from a .txt file from one path and rename the file in another path

Tags: unix, batch-rename

I have tried the below code but its taking too long to execute.
Anyone help me on this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo -n "Enter Source_Path:"
read src_path
echo -n "Enter TXTFile_Name:"
read f_name
echo -n "Enter Desti_path:"
read path
cd $src_path
while read -r line; do
  mv $path/$line $path/$line._$date
echo "Files are renamed."
```

The source path contains the text file from where file names are picked and renamed in Desti_path

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `done` closure for `while` loop

If you are using `bash` interpreter, then `while` loop should adapt to following style

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
while read -r line
do
    ...
    your_code_here
    ...
done
```